# How do I set the text in it at the beginning when the dialog opens?

Tags: java, jtextfield, joptionpane, jdialog

I have the following code that displays a `JDialog`, it shows a text field, I assume it's a `JTextField`.

How do I set the text in it at the beginning when the dialog opens?

```
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane("", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
pane.setWantsInput(true);
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "Test");
dialog.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
pane.setInitialSelectionValue("foo");
```

to set the input value that is initially displayed as selected to the user.